# jQuery dialog not firing on submit confirm

Tags: jquery

Ok, I've been working on this for a while, and I'm coming close to pulling my hair out. Here's the scenario.
I'm creating a discussion board, the posting form is called with AJAX, and when the user submits the form, I want a dialog to fire that has a warning and their comment in order to let them review and continue editing if needed.

The problem: I can't get the frickin' dialog to fire. I've tried most of the jQuery dialog answers posted here, but none of them have worked.

I'm posting the primary code here, but if needs be, I'll post the whole page. I'm using ckEditor and this form is originally called from an AJAX call itself.

Here's the code in question.

```
$('#postComment_' + id).click( function() {
                // Warn the user about submitting. Let them review their comment.
CKupdate()
$('#confirmSubmit').dialog("destroy");
var commentTitle = $('#commentSubject_' + id).val();

// This is the warning dialog that isn't working!

var commentBody = CKEDITOR.instances['comment_' + id].getData();
var NewDialog = $('<div>You are about to submit your comment.</div>'); 
// This will be where the user content will be. I stripped it out until I can get a simple warning to show.
$(NewDialog).dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
    'Submit': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        // Just close and submit.
        $('#discussionComment_' + id).ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#discussionComment_' + id + ' input:submit').html('Sending...');
                $('#newEntry').attr('id', '');
                                },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#commentBox_' + id).after(data);
                $('#discussionComment_' + id).remove();
                $('#discussionComment_' + id).hide('puff', function() { $(this).remove() }, 'fast');
                $('#content_' + id + ' a.remove').removeClass('remove').addClass('respond').html('Respond');
                $('.expand').show();
                window.location + $('#newEntry');
                $('#newEntry').children().effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('There was a problem posting your comment. Please try again.');
            }
             }); // Form submit
            },
            'Edit': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                return false; // Don't submit the form.
            }
            }
        }); 
        return false;
        });// Click to submit form.
```

Ok, let me say thanks to anyone who made it this far.
I'm also thick skinned for other crap I've screwed up, or poor form I've used. I'm trying to use good habits.

Comment: is click event working fine ?

Comment: Yes. If I put in an alert after click, it'll fire, but nothing beyond that.

Comment: Where's the code to open the dialog? I see you've gievn a dialog a bunch of options, but you never once call `$(NewDialog).dialog('open')`;

Comment: That could be something I've screwed up, but I thought $(NewDialog).dialog({ would fire the dialog on the variable NewDialog. I wouldn't be surprised if that was it...

Comment: No. You call `autoOpen: 'false'` this stops the dialog from auto opening when you create it. This requires you to invoke the open with the method I described in my initial comment. Have a nice day.

Comment: Is there a way to erase all of this, so I can go away in shame and misery without the world knowing??? Thanks for the help. I swear I tried to hide my stupidity, but it's getting harder and harder to do.

Comment: Thanks again. That worked perfectly. I think I tried so many fixes, I stopped seeing it straight. As always, you guys are a life saver.